# CV: Summary pushing Work Experience to Next Page

Tags: graphics, cv

I have a document class denoted by `temp` below:

```
\ProvidesClass{temp}[2016/02/01 CV]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrartcl}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[default,scale=0.95]{opensans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}    
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=2cm]{geometry}%1.7cm
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
\pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers

% Color definitions
\definecolor{date}{HTML}{666666} 
\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{191919} 
\definecolor{headings}{HTML}{025178}
\definecolor{subheadings}{HTML}{002648}


%%% Custom sectioning (sectsty package)
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{3pt}}
\subsectionfont{\color{headings}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}}
\subsubsectionfont{\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{3pt}}
%%% Macros
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{8888888888}          % Box to align text
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}       % Vertical space macro

\newcommand{\MyName}[1]{ % Name 
         \huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \hfill \textcolor{headings}{#1}
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}


\newcommand{\NewPart}[1]{\section*{ \color{headings} \uppercase{#1}}}

\newcommand{\PersonalEntry}[2]{
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 % Indentation
        \parbox{\spacebox}{        % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}}               % Entry name (birth, address, etc.)
        \hspace{1.5em} #2 \par}    % Entry value

\newcommand{\SkillsEntry}[2]{      % Same as \PersonalEntry
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 % Indentation
        \parbox{\spacebox}{        % Box to align text
        \textit{#1}}               % Entry name (birth, address, etc.)
        \hspace{1.5em} #2 \par}    % Entry value    
        
        
\newcommand{\workEntry}[5]{          
        %\begin{minipage}{0.08\linewidth}
    %   \includegraphics[width=1.2cm] {#5}
    %   \end{minipage}%                 
        \begin{minipage}{0.98\linewidth}  
        \noindent {\color{subheadings}\bfseries\uppercase {#1}}, {\color{subheadings}\textit{#3}}  
        \hfill  {\color{headings}\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}#2}   
        \par    
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \normalsize #4%\small #4 % Description
        \normalsize \par         
        \end{minipage}         
}
        
\newcommand{\EducationEntry}[5]{     
        %\begin{minipage}{0.08\linewidth}
    %   \includegraphics[width=1.2cm] {#5}
    %   \end{minipage}%                    
        \begin{minipage}{0.98\linewidth}  
        \noindent {\color{subheadings}\bfseries\uppercase {#1}} 
        \hfill {\color{headings}\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}#2}
        \par    
        \noindent {\color{subheadings}\textit{#3}} \par 
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \normalsize #4%\small #4 % Description
        \normalsize \par         
        \end{minipage}        
 }

\newcommand{\flag}[1]{
    \includegraphics[height=9pt, width= 15pt]{#1}
}     

\newcommand{\software}[1]{
    \includegraphics[height=9pt]{#1}
}  

\newcommand{\softwareb}[1]{
    \raisebox{-.6\height}{\includegraphics[height=18pt]{#1}}
}
```

The problem I am facing is that whenever I write my summary, this forces the Work Experience part of my CV to the next page even when the Summary is not occupying the whole page. How do I stop the CV Summary from pushing the Work Experience to the next page of the CV? Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{temp} % KOMA-article class
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}                         
\begin{document}
    
    %\begin{minipage}{.2\linewidth}
    % \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{photo}
    %\end{minipage}      
    \begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}
        \MyName{ ABCD EFG HIJ}
        \sepspace
        \noindent
        
        \hfill 1234567890|ghirtorfg@gmail.com
        
        %\hfill yourwebsite.com
        
        %\hfill (+263)774794598  
        
    \end{minipage}
    
    \NewPart{Summary}{}
    
    \lipsum[1-1]
    
    \NewPart{Work experience}{\noindent
        
        \workEntry{Ghhrieie i3i3}{2021- 2023}{Programmer}{\begin{itemize}[label=\textcolor{headings}{\textbullet},itemsep=0em]
                \item   There is another package named blindtext which can generate a single paragraph of dummy lorem ipsum text to even an entire document with the dummy text.
                \item There is another package named blindtext which can generate a single paragraph of dummy lorem ipsum text to even an entire document with the dummy text.
                \item There is another package named blindtext which can generate a single paragraph of dummy lorem ipsum text to even an entire document with the dummy text.
                \item There is another package named blindtext which can generate a single paragraph of dummy lorem ipsum text to even an entire document with the dummy text.
                \item There is another package named blindtext which can generate a single paragraph of dummy lorem ipsum text to even an entire document with the dummy text.
                \item There is another package named blindtext which can generate a single paragraph of dummy lorem ipsum text to even an entire document with the dummy text.
                \item There is another package named blindtext which can generate a single paragraph of dummy lorem ipsum text to even an entire document with the dummy text.
                \item There is another package named blindtext which can generate a single paragraph of dummy lorem ipsum text to even an entire document with the dummy text.
                \item There is another package named blindtext which can generate a single paragraph of dummy lorem ipsum text to even an entire document with the dummy text.
                \item There is another package named blindtext which can generate a single paragraph of dummy lorem ipsum text to even an entire document with the dummy text.
                \item There is another package named blindtext which can generate a single paragraph of dummy lorem ipsum text to even an entire document with the dummy text.
                \item There is another package named blindtext which can generate a single paragraph of dummy lorem ipsum text to even an entire document with the dummy text.
                \item  There is another package named blindtext which can generate a single paragraph of dummy lorem ipsum text to even an entire document with the dummy text.
                \item There is another package named blindtext which can generate a single paragraph of dummy lorem ipsum text to even an entire document with the dummy text.
                \item There is another package named blindtext which can generate a single paragraph of dummy lorem ipsum text to even an entire document with the dummy text.
        \end{itemize} }{IMG/writeL}}
    
    
    \sepspace
    
    
    \NewPart{Education}{}
    \noindent
    
    \EducationEntry{Afffgg}{2013}{Hererir School}{ Aisieieieeieii fjrrirurr rrirrrir} {IMG/I}
    
    
    \sepspace
    
    \EducationEntry{Afffgg}{2013}{Hererir School}{ Aisieieieeieii fjrrirurr rrirrrir} {IMG/agh}
    
    
    \sepspace
    
    \EducationEntry{BSc Hons in Bdhdueuerue}{2018}{University of JIieieiee}{Tagdfg eeeiuei fororoedmeke eje} {IMG/TUM}
    
    \sepspace
    
    \NewPart{Skills \& Interests}{}
    \hspace{3mm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth} 
        
        \begin{tabular}[t]{ l l }
        A  & Native Speaker \\
        B  & Professional user \\
        C & Professional Proficiency \\
        D  & Conversational level \\
        E  & Conversational level \\
        \end{tabular}
        
        \sepspace
        
    \end{minipage}
    %
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth} 
    
    
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l l}
Ghhh     & This software experience. fillertext fillertext fillertex\\
    Ghhh         & This software experience. fillertext fillertext fillertex\\
Ghhh     & This software experience. fillertext fillertext fillertex\\
Ghhh         & This software experience. fillertext fillertext fillertex\\
    Ghhh     & This software experience. fillertext fillertext fillertex\\
    \end{tabular}
    
    
    
    \end{minipage}
    
    %\begin{tabular}{l l}
    %\software{IMG/soft/Matlab}      & This software experience. fillertext fillertext fillertex\\
    %\software{IMG/soft/office}          & This software experience. fillertext fillertext fillertex\\
    %\software{IMG/soft/Matlab}      & This software experience. fillertext fillertext fillertex\\
    
    %hobby1,   & Small achievments text. fillertext fillertext fillertex fillertext fillertex\\
    %hobby2,   & Small achievments text. fillertext fillertext fillertex fillertext fillertex\\
    %hobby3,   & Small achievments text. fillertext fillertext fillertex fillertext fillertex\\
    %\end{tabular}
    

    References
    %%% ------------------------------------------------------------
    
    %%% References
    %%% ------------------------------------------------------------
    
\end{document}
```